# Sonarqube not starting as an windows service

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to launch sonarqube as an windows service.

Steps that i followed.

1-InstalINTService.bat started

2-went into sonarqube properties-logon tab-

[image]

Entered network service in object name

When i try to start sonarqube as a service .I get the following error

[image]

My Sonar log

```
2015.02.27 13:58:50 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2015.02.27 14:05:57 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
```

[image]

I could not see my Login Here .How can i add my login name here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try with another user, this one has not the rights to start the SonarQube service. For more details: http://qualilogy.com/en/migrate-sonarqube-tomcat-to-windows-service/.

Regards.

Comment: Other users are also not starting the service.

Comment: The user who is logged when installing the Windows service should be able to start it.

Comment: In my edit ,i have added all the users available who can be associated with the service ,but no user is able to start the service.

Answer (score 0):

While installing SonarQube as a service in windows, it selects "Local System Account" as privileged user to start the service. Choose the second option "This Account" in properties of that service and select "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" and save it. Now start the service. It will run properly.

Regards,
Bhakti Prasad Panda

Comment: The initial problem seems to be that Sonar does not start with the "Network Service" account. Using a different account does not really answer the question, why it is not starting with the selected account.

Answer (score 0):

It might not recognizing the local system user. That's why we should try with some other options available on desk. In log on tab choose "Local Service" instead of "Network Service". It worked for me.